# Is there is any way to get users location by IP address?

Tags: php, json, jquery

Is there any kind of API or third party service that provides users location (state/city) as return value by submitting IP Address ??

Comment: Possible duplicate question ! Go through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+geolocation+ip

Answer (score 1):

This form of IP lookup is called Geolocate by IP.  Try Googling for this and you will find a bunch of different companies offering the service either Paid or Free.

From my experience, if you want to get an accurate lookup, you will need to pay.  If you don't mind the service to be off (quite often), then go with the free.

Maxmind seems to be the leader in this domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [website](http://www.ip2location.com/free.asp) or download the database to use it the way you want

Another [webiste](http://software77.net/geo-ip/) (Free)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to us an IP to Location geolocation service. This is an example : http://www.maxmind.com/app/city

There is also a free version that doesn't give a precise location - http://software77.net/geo-ip/